# Can I move windows 10 from external hdd to internal ssd?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, format

I want to install the old windows version on my laptop instead of the cracked version which is installed now, the old version is in the external hard drive and the cracked version on the internal ssd. So how can I remove the cracked and install the new. Knowing that I have no important data in internal.

Comment: The best way is to back up the SSD and install Windows 10 fresh on it. That will work best in the long run.

Comment: There a variety of third-party applications that will restore an image of a system and restore it on another, this image, is taken from a hdd.  As long as the external hdd is currently bootable, using on of those third-party applications that support doing that, should work.  However, based on what you have provide, it's difficult to determine if what you want is possible.  **I absolutely will not make a software recommendation.**

Comment: I will answer this as a basic disk replacement, ignoring the "cracked OS" comment and just assuming the SSD is blank... Macrium Reflect is a great choice for moving partitions and operating systems in general, but there are others out there just as good, probably some better.

Comment: @acejavelin Macrium reflect would be good for him/his task. I don't know if macrium reflect can move partitions.. maybe it can, but he doesn't want to move a partition.   Macrium can make an image of his disk and put it on another disk.

Comment: @barlop It can move partitions, including resizing them on the fly if necessary in most cases, for moving disks/partitions between drives of dislike size. It also supports most Linux and Mac file systems as well.

Comment: @acejavelin good to know.. I remember at one point trying to copy a partition to another hard drive or something like that and having some issues because Windows required two partitions. , you know like that 100MB "system reserved" partition I see with Win7. I had used Macrium and then ran something like `bootcfg /rebuild` to try to find the thing and things weren't working.   And advice I got here was that I should really have used a native windows tool to do things(rather than a third party program like macrium), I think a windows native tool called DISM was mentioned.

Comment: Windows has always natively supported creating and applying images (Windows  ≥8: `DISM` || Windows ≤7: `ImageX`, which I cover more in-depth within my answer), with 3rd-party software often creating configuration issues, generally being an inconvenience since their processes are often not able to be done natively within WinPE/WinRE _(e.g. 3rd-parties often require their own boot media - inefficient & inconvenient - and since all have access to WinPE via a Windows install USB, coupled with all versions at least as far back as Win7 having a WinRE partition, cons outweigh the pros they offer)_.

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to install a fresh windows but the only way to clone your windows to your internal ssd is to use a cloning software.

There are several cloning software that can do this ([easeUs](https://www.easeus.com/backup-utility/how-to-migrate-to-a-solid-state-disk-without-reinstalling-windows.html), [samsung data migration](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/), etc.).

The problem is that if you have a large hdd with lots of files on it and no partitions, you are going to have to remove all your data since it would be a waste of time to clone them. Otherwise you'll be fine. And never mention a cracked windows again!

Answer (score 1):

If not clean installing, you would use [`DISM`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14) for capturing an image of the old Windows install on the external HDD, as well as to apply it to the internal HDD, and [`DiskPart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart) to configure the partitions prior to applying the image within WinPE/WinRE:

- Windows XP ≥ 10 has *always* natively supported imaging of partitions or individual directories:

  - It's impossible for an ESD/WIM to become corrupted, provided imaging commands are always issued with `/CheckIntegrity /Verify`
  - Imaging the System partition is slightly different than other partitions, as it can only be imaged from WinPE/WinRE
  - Microsoft's [Windows Imaging File Format](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13096) whitepaper explains the WIM format

    - WIMs *(**W**indows **IM**age)* can capture an entire partition
    - ESDs *(**E**lectronic **S**oftware **D**istribution)* can only capture a System partition and must use  `/Compress:Recovery` *(algorithm is ~33% more efficient than `/Compress:Max`)*

      - Windows ≥10: Can only be used for PBR [[**P**ush-**B**utton **R**eset](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/push-button-reset-overview)] *exported* images
- All WinPE/WinRE  [WIMs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/wim-vs-ffu-image-file-formats) have `DISM` included within them:

  - **WinPE:** **Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment 
     *(Windows Setup boot media: **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>** to access terminal)*
  - **WinRE:** **Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment 
     *(WinRE is a WinPE image containing extra WinPE [Optional Components](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-add-packages--optional-components-reference) vital to recovery)*

---

#### Imaging:

Specify exclusions or exceptions by creating a [**`WimScript.ini`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-configuration-list-and-wimscriptini-files-winnext) config file, with `/ScratchDir` being required in WinPE since it only has 32MB of scratch [temp] space by default:

1. **Download the [Windows Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10):**

   1. *Install on another PC* saves it as an ISO, then create a bootable USB with [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/)
   2. Boot the Windows Install USB and open a terminal via **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>**
2. **Either *Capture* or *Append* an image:**

   - **[Capture Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#capture-image):**

     ```powershell
     # Windows ≥8: DISM
       Dism /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2020.10.09 @ 08:00" /Compress:Max /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"
     ```

     - Change `/Compress:Max` to `/Compress:Fast` if not saving captured image to an SSD 
        *`Max` will take significant time to compress on a mechanical HDD, but if retaining the image as a backup, use [**`/Export-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#export-image) to change the compression to `Max` when booted to Windows*
     - For managing size constraints, images can be split into multiple read-only `.swm` files via [**`/Split-Image`**](http://ttps://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#split-image)
   - **[Append Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#append-image):**

     ```powershell
     # Windows ≥8: DISM
       Dism /Append-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:" /Name:"Windows Backup" /Description:"Base Image 2020.10.09 @ 08:00" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"
     ```

     - Compression is locked to the value set when the base image was captured
     - Individual indexes can be deleted via [**`/Delete-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#delete-image) or exported to their own image via [**`/Export-Image`**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#export-image)
3. **[Apply Image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#apply-image):**

   ```powershell
   # Windows ≥8: DISM
     Dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim" /Index:1 /ApplyDir:"C:" /CheckIntegrity /Verify /ScratchDir:"Z:"
   ```

   - Prior to applying, get [Image Info](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-image-management-command-line-options-s14#get-imageinfo), ensuring correct index [image] is being applied:

     ```powershell
     Dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:"Z:\Base.wim"
     ```
   - If applying an OS image, the following must be ran prior to exiting WinPE/WinRE:

     - BIOS:

       ```powershell
       BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD
       ```
     - UEFI:

       ```powershell
       BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD
       ```

---

#### Configure Partitions:

1. **Use [`DiskPart`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart):** *(select the OS drive the image is being applied to)* 
    *Assumes no data on disk is being preserved, as `clean` wipes the drive's partition table*

   ```powershell
   DiskPart

   Lis Dis
   Sel Dis #
   Clean
   ```

   **UEFI:**

   ```powershell
   Convert Gpt
   ```
2. **Create WinRE partition:** *(must have 320MB free (`WinRE.wim` is ~300MB in size)*

   - **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Offset=1024 Size=665 Id=27
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=WinRE
     ```
   - **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Offset=1024 Size=665 Id=de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=WinRE
     Gpt Attributes=0x8000000000000001
     ```
3. **Create boot partition:**

   - **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Size=100
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=Boot
     Active
     ```
   - **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par EFI Size=100
     Format Quick Fs=FAT32 Label=EFI
     Assign Letter=Y
     Cre Par Msr Size=16
     ```
4. **Create System partition:**

   - **Rest of the disk as the System partition:** *(if `C:` can't be assigned: change 4 & 5 to another letter)* 
      **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     Exit
     ```

     **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     Assign Letter=C
     Exit
     ```
   - **Additional partitions after the [200GB] System partition:** *(multiply size wanted by 1024: `200*1024=204800`)* 
      *If storing User Data directories on a partition other than `C:\` (recommended), max size required is ~300GB* 
      **BIOS:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Size=204800
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     Exit
     ```

     **UEFI:**

     ```powershell
     Cre Par Pri Size=204800 Id=ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
     Format Quick Fs=NTFS Label=System
     Assign Letter=C
     Exit
     ```
5. **Resolve any boot issues:** *(Once system image has been applied)* 
    **BIOS:**

   ```powershell
   BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD
   ```

   **UEFI:**

   ```powershell
   # Create EFI directories and enter:
     MkDir "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"
     Cd /d "Y:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot"

   # Create EFI boot structure:
     BootRec /Fixboot

     # If Access Denied error occurs:
       BcdBoot C:\Windows /s C: /f UEFI

   # Resolve any other boot issues:
     BootRec /FixMBR && BootRec /RebuildBCD
   ```
6. **Remove EFI mountpoint *(if applicable)* and Reboot 
    UEFI:**

   ```powershell
   DiskPart

   Sel Vol Y
   Remove
   Exit
   ```